# Compress HTML using Apache

Tags: php, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I'm using Apache to compress render HTML files but it's not working. Why? I'm usng hostmonster servers and YII PHP framework.

**.htaccess:**

```
<IfModule deflate_module>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/javascript text/css application/json application/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Do NOT compress localhost
#SetEnvIf Remote_Host 127.0.0.1 no-gzip

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is [`mod_deflate`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html). Not `deflate_module`.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate>
```

**Note:** It looks like you took your code from the documentation. As noted in the docs, *Do not use this unless you fully understand all the configuration details.* As such, maybe start with just `AddOutputFilterByType` and expand from there.